# Rabin fingerprint using .NET

Tags: .net, fingerprint, rabin

Is there any rabin fingerprint implementation using .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just googled:

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d863959/dotnet/general-dotnet/contribuez/algorithm-rabin-fingerprint/

Comment: Not able to deal with continuously zero bytes.